# Used "Get" for stage management. Created controllers correctly but values are not updating. When I go to another page and come back then It is fine

Tags: flutter, get

[image]

I wanted update real time this item count ex: 1 and total amount Ex: 390

Cart Item

```
  class CartItem extends StatelessWidget {
  ProductItemModel productItemModel;
  CartController cartController = Get.put(CartController());

  CartItem({
    super.key,
    required this.productItemModel,
  });

  void increase(ProductItemModel productItemModel) {
    cartController.increaseItemAmount(productItemModel);
  }

  void decrease(ProductItemModel productItemModel) {
    cartController.decreaseItemAmount(productItemModel);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        border: Border(
          top: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black),
          bottom: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 120,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              child: Image.network(
                productItemModel.imagesUrl,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Product Name: ${productItemModel.title}",
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 40,
                            ),
                            RichText(
                              text: TextSpan(
                                  text: "Rs. ${productItemModel.price}",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.green, fontSize: 14),
                                  children: [
                                    TextSpan(
                                      text: "/${productItemModel.unit}",
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                    ),
                                  ]),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: [
                                InkWell(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      cartController.deleteFromCart(
                                          productItemModel.documentId!);
                                    },
                                    child: Icon(Icons.delete)),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 10,
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  width: 111,
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                    children: [
                                      InkWell(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          decrease(productItemModel);
                                        },
                                        child: Text("-"),
                                      ),
                                      Obx(() {
                                        final amount = cartController.amount(
                                            productItemModel.documentId!);
                                        print(amount);
                                        return Text(
                                          amount.toString(),
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      }),
                                      InkWell(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          increase(productItemModel);
                                        },
                                        child: Text("+"),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

CartScreen

```
class CartScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  CartScreen({Key? key});
  CartController cartController = Get.find();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          CartTitleWidget(),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: GetX<CartController>(
                init: Get.put<CartController>(CartController()),
                builder: (CartController controller) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true, // Set shrinkWrap to true
                    itemCount: cartController.cartsList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return CartItem(
                        productItemModel: cartController.cartsList[index],
                      );
                    },
                  );
                }),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  // Obx(() {
                  //   return Text(cartController.totalPrice.toString());
                  // }),
                  GetX<CartController>(builder: (controller) {
                    return Text(controller.totalAmount.toString());
                  }),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text(
                      "Pay Now",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

CartController

```
  class CartController extends GetxController {
  List<ProductItemModel> carts = <ProductItemModel>[].obs;
  List<ProductItemModel> get cartsList => carts;

  get totalCount => carts.fold(0, (sum, item) => sum + 1).obs;
  get totalAmount => carts.fold(0.0, (sum, item) => sum + item.price).obs;

  int amount(String documentId) =>
      (carts.firstWhere((element) => element.documentId == documentId)).amount!;

  // Create a method to add or update products in the cart
  void addToCart(ProductItemModel productItemModel) {
    // Check if an item with the same documentId exists in the cart
    final existingItemIndex = carts.indexWhere(
      (item) => item.documentId == productItemModel.documentId,
    );

    if (existingItemIndex != -1) {
      // If it exists, increment the amount by one
      carts[existingItemIndex].amount =
          (carts[existingItemIndex].amount ?? 0) + 1;
    } else {
      // If it doesn't exist, add it to the cart
      productItemModel.amount = 1;
      carts.add(productItemModel);
    }
  }

  void deleteFromCart(String documentId) {
    carts.removeWhere((cart) => cart.documentId == documentId);
    print(documentId);
  }

  void increaseItemAmount(ProductItemModel productItemModel) {
    // Check if an item with the same documentId exists in the cart
    final existingItemIndex = carts.indexWhere(
      (item) => item.documentId == productItemModel.documentId,
    );

    if (existingItemIndex != -1) {
      // If it exists, increment the amount by one
      carts[existingItemIndex].amount =
          (carts[existingItemIndex].amount ?? 0) + 1;
    }
  }

  void decreaseItemAmount(ProductItemModel productItemModel) {
    // Check if an item with the same documentId exists in the cart
    final existingItemIndex = carts.indexWhere(
      (item) => item.documentId == productItemModel.documentId,
    );

    if (existingItemIndex != -1) {
      // If it exists, increment the amount by one
      carts[existingItemIndex].amount =
          (carts[existingItemIndex].amount ?? 0) - 1;
      if (carts[existingItemIndex].amount! < 1) {
        carts.removeAt(existingItemIndex);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I click delete button then below total amount reducing correctly but when I press "-" It is not updating. Used get state management dependency with flutter. Tried with chatgpt also. I am stuck in this. Your kind consideration is highly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the commenting but it is better if you have an idea about issue let me know if you have a idea about it. Your kind consideration is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties of `ProductItemModel` are not reactive. Use `refresh` manually notify about the change.

```
void decreaseItemAmount(ProductItemModel productItemModel) {
...
  if (existingItemIndex != -1) {
    // If it exists, increment the amount by one
    carts[existingItemIndex].amount =
        (carts[existingItemIndex].amount ?? 0) - 1;
    carts.refresh()
...
  }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry. I used that model to check that item is exist in the cart list. Do I need to check with "carts" variable right? And your suggestion shows "The method 'refresh' isn't defined for the type 'List'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'refresh'." Thank you for your answer and looking forward a reply from you. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the response I tried with update() function and wrapped cart Item with get builder. Now working fine. thanks for the help.

Comment: Note for future developers : The issue with my productItemModel.amount not updating in real time is likely because I am using obs to wrap the carts list. When you use obs, changes to the list are not reflected in the UI immediately. Instead, the UI is only updated when the carts.refresh() method is called.

To fix this, I can either call the carts.refresh() method after making changes to the list, or I can use GetBuilder to wrap the CartItem widget. GetBuilder will automatically rebuild the widget whenever the carts list is updated.